# Using Date to create a time since last appearance column

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive been trying to figure out how I can use the date of the match to see how many days ago did the away team play and the home team play. By creating a Rest column for each I am trying to establish times played between there last appearance. I am assuming a list would have to be created but I cant quite grasp how that would work.

**Script:**

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

for i in range(20001,21271):
    req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?site=en_nhl&gamePk=20180' + str(i) + '&leaderGameTypes=R&expand=schedule.broadcasts.all,schedule.radioBroadcasts,schedule.teams,schedule.ticket,schedule.game.content.media.epg')
    data = req.json()

    for item in data['dates']:
        date = item['date']
        games = item['games']
        for game in games:
            gamePk = game['gamePk']
            season = game['season']
            teams = game['teams']
            home = teams['home']
            home_tm = home['team']['abbreviation']           
            away = teams['away']
            away_tm = away['team']['abbreviation']


            print(date, gamePk, away_tm, home_tm)
```

Comment: Okay, I executed your script. It goes on and on with printing stuff out in this format: `2018-11-08 2018020228 EDM FLA`. I would suppose that the date is in the second column, cuz you wouldn't check for *already played* matches with date in the future. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the dataframe first of all:

```
import pandas as pd
kp = []
for i in range(20001,21271):
    req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule?site=en_nhl&gamePk=20180' + str(i) + '&leaderGameTypes=R&expand=schedule.broadcasts.all,schedule.radioBroadcasts,schedule.teams,schedule.ticket,schedule.game.content.media.epg')
    data = req.json()

    for item in data['dates']:
        date = item['date']
        games = item['games']
        for game in games:
            gamePk = game['gamePk']
            season = game['season']
            teams = game['teams']
            home = teams['home']
            home_tm = home['team']['abbreviation']           
            away = teams['away']
            away_tm = away['team']['abbreviation']

            print date, gamePk, away_tm, home_tm

            kp.append([date, gamePk, away_tm, home_tm])

df    = pd.DataFrame(kp, columns=['Date','Time','Home', 'Away'])
df.to_csv('matches.csv', sep=' ', header=True, index=False)
```

Of course you only need to run this once and save it as a csc. Then run the script...

```
def find_last(match_date, da, team):

        home_play = da[da['Home'] == team].tail(1) #then find last matches played at home, select greatest
        away_play = da[da['Away'] == team].tail(1) #"  " find last matches played at away, select greatest

        #then take the last match played, either home or away, whichever is more recent
        if home_play.empty and away_play.empty:
            print team, "no_matches before this date"
            last_match = 'NA'

        elif home_play.empty:
            last_match = away_play.Date.item()

        elif away_play.empty:
            last_match = home_play.Date.item()            

        else:
            last_match = max([home_play.Date.item(), away_play.Date.item()])


        if last_match != 'NA':

            #And then subtract this from "todays" date (match_date)
            duration_since_last = pd.to_datetime(match_date) - pd.to_datetime(last_match)

            print "Team:", team
            print "Todays game date  = ", match_date
            print "Last match played = ", last_match
            print "Rest Period       = ", duration_since_last

            print

            return duration_since_last

df = pd.read_csv('matches.txt', sep=' ')


for k in df.index:

    home_team  = df.Home[k]
    away_team  = df.Away[k]
    match_date = df.Date[k]

    #we want to find all date values less than todays match date.
    da        = df[df['Date'] < match_date]

    if not da.empty:
        for team in [home_team,away_team]:
            print "Record", k, home_team, 'vs', away_team

            find_last(match_date, da, team)

        print '________________________________________'
```

You should end up with output that gives the rest days:

```
________________________________________
Record 54 WPG vs NSH
Team: WPG
Todays game date  =  2018-10-11
Last match played =  2018-10-09
Rest Period       =  2 days 00:00:00

Record 54 WPG vs NSH
Team: NSH
Todays game date  =  2018-10-11
Last match played =  2018-10-09
Rest Period       =  2 days 00:00:00

________________________________________
Record 55 CHI vs MIN
Team: CHI
Todays game date  =  2018-10-11
Last match played =  2018-10-07
Rest Period       =  4 days 00:00:00

Record 55 CHI vs MIN
Team: MIN
Todays game date  =  2018-10-11
Last match played =  2018-10-06
Rest Period       =  5 days 00:00:00

________________________________________
```

Comment: For the `['home'] == 'MTL'` for it to check both home and away since we are checking if the team has played not just home and not just away but both wouldnt it have to be `== 'Home' or 'Away'].tail` ? Does that make sense? Or should i change the loop to only be team and not home and away?

Comment: @Michael T Johnson I will gove you a more complete solution, I have a few minutes to spare. Give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I appreciate that!

Comment: @Michael T Johnson Thats ok. See up date.

Comment: You used this with my above script and didnt change any names along the way? I get quite a few errors. One being the print and the other object names.

Comment: @ Michael T Johnson No, you need to put all the data into a pandas dataframe for this to work. See update for how to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! I appreciate you taking the time to explain this!

Comment: @Michael T Johnson  thats fine, accept the answer and we're done.